# How to install theme in recent Magento on Centos 7 (no GUI, VM)?

Tags: theme, installation, magento2.2.2, linux

There are 2 directories of Porto theme.zip on my Windows desktop - "app" and "pub". I put them by simply dropping from desktop into `/app/design/frontend` Centos directory via WinSCP. In my opinion full default path after dropping looks like (by WinSCP): `/var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend`. Than I run commands like (but it is no helps): 
`setup:upgrade`, `setup:di:compile`, `setup:static-content:deploy`, `indexer:reindex`, `cache:flush`
After that I go to Admin Panel in Content > Design > Themes but nothing. I need any commands, different paths?

Also I have Composer but I still not able to create commands by myself or paths from my Windows desktop to Centos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was wrong path. `/var/www/html/magento` - is okey. And no any different or additional up or sub-directories for uploading, only two after extracting needed - "app" and "pub".

Answer (score 0):

Have you make sure that the copied files has the right permission (the webserver user can actually read the file?)

Comment: No, I didn't do anything. Just in the beginning there was a problem with dropping via WinSCP, was not enough permission rights. I solved it by (something like) `sudo chown -R -v <user> /home/<user>/vendor`. It has become possible to move folders after that.